# Pagination: change page display (angular2)

Tags: angular, pagination

I'm implementing a pagination for a list of hours [00:00,00:06,...]. I'm using NgxPaginationModule. My items per page will be fixed, but instead of having [1,2,3,...] for page, I would like to have [0h-2h,2h-4h,....].

```
            <div  class=" pagination  justify-content-center">
            <pagination-controls
              [id]="config2.id"
              [maxSize]="maxSize2"
              [directionLinks]="directionLinks2"
              [autoHide]="autoHide2"
              [previousLabel]="labels2.previousLabel | translate"
              [nextLabel]="labels2.nextLabel | translate"
              [screenReaderPaginationLabel]="labels2.screenReaderPaginationLabel"
              [screenReaderPageLabel]="associatePagination6minPage(labels2.screenReaderPageLabel)"
              [screenReaderCurrentLabel]="labels2.screenReaderCurrentLabel"
              (pageChange)="pagination2.onPageChange($event)"></pagination-controls>


          </div>
```

Comment: Did you try their example with `pagination-template` ? https://github.com/michaelbromley/ngx-pagination

Answer (score 0):

From the Readme

> If you require a more customised set of controls, you will need to use the `PaginationControlsDirective` and implement your own component.

So what that basically means is to create your own component that uses the `pagination-template` and add your own implementation.

You can look at the default pagination [component](https://github.com/michaelbromley/ngx-pagination/blob/master/src/pagination-controls.component.ts) and [template](https://github.com/michaelbromley/ngx-pagination/blob/master/src/template.ts) and try to roll out your own.

Good luck.